# Идея для множественного наследования по схеме

Tags: c++, ооп

Помогите, пожалуйста, придумать идею для реализации множественного наследования по схеме:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это безумие ...

Comment: это всего лишь лабораторная)

Comment: B - человек, D1 - Ученик, D2 - Ходящий_в_ВУЗ, D3 - Учитель D4 - Студент (ученик наследован приватно, так как учится - скрывает). D5 - преподаватель (с функцией учить та же проблема)

Comment: @KoVadim "Тебе бы, начальник, не программы, тебе бы фантастику писать..." (перефразируя Ручечника :))

Comment: Немного не понимаю, а чем "ученик" от "студент" отличаться будет?